#  World of Warcraft Launcher crashes on Wine

Tags: wine, games

Just downloaded the installer for WoW from eu.battle.net, and the Launcher it crashes after 1-2 minutes (so the new patches cannot be installed).

I've tried looking on Google, but I was unable to find an answer.

[Terminal output](http://pastebin.com/RTJAuqbH)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and Wine are you running.
Please run `wine --version` in a terminal

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 (currently Beta 2)

Comment: $ wine --version
wine-1.4

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure you have disabled p2p connections in downloader options

2) If the launcher freezes (in the middle) kill the background task "wow-4.2.1.2736-enUS-tools-downloader.exe

3) If points 2) and 3) dont work for you create a new wineprefix and restart the launcher.